# Not closing ssh

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I have a korn 88 shell script which creates a folder on the remote host using the following command:

```
ssh $user@$host "mkdir -p $somedir" 2>> $Log
```

and after that transfers a bunch of files in a loop using this

```
scp -o keepalive=yes $somedir/$file $user@$host:$somedir
```

I wonder if first command will leave connection open after script ends?

Comment: It won't. You can check it yourself using `ps` or `top`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the commands opens and closes its own connection. It's easy to use a tool like [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to verify this.

This is a consequence of the fact that the [`exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit) system call used to terminate a process closes all open file descriptors including socket file descriptors. Closing a socket closes the connection behind the socket.

Comment: that means that if I have 10 files to transfer I will have 10 + 1 = 11 connections opened and closed during script execution... is there more efficient way to do this?

Comment: There are many ways to copy a bunch of files on a single connection. One good alternative is [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) (see comment by William Pursell). Also, scp can copy multiple files, see [man scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp).

Answer (score 3):

New-enough versions of ssh have the ability to multiplex several virtual connections over a single physical connection.  So what you could do is start up some long-running ssh command in the background with connection multiplexing enabled, and then subsequent connections will re-use that connection with much faster startup times.  See the  manpage for `ssh_config` for info on connection multiplexing, relevant options are `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath`.

But as William Pursell suggests, `rsync` is probably easier and faster, if it's an option.